# how programmatically transform a function type T so that the first parameter of a given type V is removed?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an `Action` interface representing a call signature:

```
interface Action {
    (
        product: Product,
        value: Value,
        cart: Cart,
        payload?: { [key: string]: any }
    ): void;
}

interface Cart {
    name: string;
}

interface Product {
    name: string;
}

interface Value {
    id: string;
}
```

and I'd like to transform it to a version without the `Value` parameter so I can use it like:

```
interface UpdateAction {
    (
        product: Product,
        cart: Cart,
        payload?: { [key: string]: any }
    ): void;
}

const updateProduct: UpdateAction = (product, cart) => {
    cart.name = product.name; 
};

const Reducer = (
    product: Product,
    message: Message,
    cart: Cart,
    value:Value
) => {
    const { action, payload } = message;

    switch (action) {
        case 'update':
            updateProduct(product, cart);
            break;
        default: {
            throw new Error('Unknown type');
        }
    }
};
```

But I don't want to manually define `UpdateAction`; instead, I'd like to programmatically transform `Action` into `UpdateAction` via a type function like `RemoveFirstParamOfType<Action, Value>`.

**How can I write a type function `RemoveFirstParamOfType<T, V>` to remove the first function parameter of type `V` from a call signature?**

I tried to make a [testable example](https://playcode.io/1267595) in ts playground. You can try it out.

Comment: Yes, you should replace “void“ with the actual state in the Action interface

Comment: hey @Greg, thanks for the comment. I replaced `void` with the current state and in updateProduct it throws this error: 
"Type '(value: Value, products: Products, payload: { [key: string]: any; }) => void' is not assignable to type 'Action'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type '{ value: Value, products: Products, payload: { [key: string]: any; }}'."

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing the code to be a [mre] others can copy and paste into their own IDEs and demonstrate the issue for themselves; there should be no undeclared things like  `Message`, `Product`, `Products`, `Value`.

Comment: If it was a regular interface, I'd use Pick or Omit to get the necessary types/arguments but here it is an interface for a call signature with positional arguments

Comment: It is still not a minimal reproducible example. See here: https://tsplay.dev/wjDv2m I get tons of unrelated errors, but not the one you mentioned.

Comment: Let me know when you're done editing; I still see `Value` in there; hopefully you're testing this out in your own standalone IDE so you can anticipate these things instead of just reacting to comments

Comment: @jcalz I apologize for not proper code example. Now it should be testable

Comment: @jcalz you can also check it on ts playground, here is the link https://playcode.io/1267595

Comment: @vr. thanks for the comment. Here is the testable example https://playcode.io/1267595 or copy/paste the code in your sandbox

Comment: I'm confused about what you're trying to achieve here; which code are you trying to change? You ask how to remove unused arguments... from where exactly?  If you don't want to send `value` to `updateAction()` then don't send it, and change the definition of `updateAction()` accordingly; if you want to derive its type from `Action` you can, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wgDY9N), but it's not obvious why you care about `Action` at all.  I think in order to be a [mre] it should be apparent from the code what the issue is, and I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: @jcalz  thanks for the example. I was passing without the  "value"  argument, as you might have seen already.

typescript is not my best skill and I couldn't figure out how to implement  "Tail" and "UpdateAction" type. 
Can you, please,  post your answer so that it will be more visible for the community and and explain how you implemented those 2 types.

Comment: "as you might have seen already" no, where would I see that?  If you want to know specifically how you can transform a call signature of the form `(x: X, y: Y, z: Z) => T` to a call signature of the form `(y: Y, z: Z) => T`, where the first parameter has been removed, could you please [edit] the question to ask that explicitly?  Or, if you're looking for something more general (e.g., transform a call signature so it removes the `N`th parameter given `N extends number`) please ask that instead?

Comment: It is not about a call signature, where  the first parameter has been removed, but about the order of the parameters in Action interface, try to change the positon of `value`  type in Action interface and you will have again the same problem

Comment: Then you don't want `Tail` at all.  Can you explain how we should identify the one to remove?  Is it the one of type `Value` (which is possible) or is it the one whose *label* is `value` (which is **impossible**, parameter names are unobservable by the type system)?

Comment: @jcalz It is the one of type Value

Comment: So then does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WkDVjw) meet your needs?  If so, please [edit] the question to explicitly say something like "how can I programmatically transform a function type `T` so that the first parameter of a given type `V` is removed; so, `Transform<Action, Value>` would be equivalent to `( product: Product, cart: Cart, payload?: { [key: string]: any }) => void`?"  Or whatever question you're trying to ask.  I'm happy to write up an answer but the question should be obvious and not only present in the comments.

Comment: @jcalz cool. One more question, please. 
What if instead of value I want to skip another argument, can I do like" type UpdateAction = RemoveFirstParamOfType<Action, Value | Product> "

Comment: @jcalz Question is updated

Comment: That's just the title; please edit the question body also to be clear what the question is.  ... also, it seems you want to remove *all* parameters of a given type and not just the *first* one?  So `Value | Product` would cause all `Value` and `Product` arguments to be removed?

Comment: Also note that your `Cart` and your `Product` arguments are identical and there's no way to target one and not the other; TS's type system is structural and not nominal.  Maybe you'd better leave the question about removing a single argument instead of expanding the scope now that someone has started to address your original question.  If you have followup questions you could make new question posts for them.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'd love to learn more about typescript and I appreciate your time you spent helping me.

Comment: Okay I've posted an answer.  Note from the comments that I asked you to please edit the question body and not just the title.  Could you do that?  If you want me to do it instead, just let me know and I'd be happy to.

Comment: Yes please. I would be grateful if you would do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to write a `RemoveFirstParamOfType<T, V>` function which takes a function type `T` and another type `V`, and returns a new function type which is the same as `T` except that the first parameter assignable to `V` has been removed.  So `RemoveFirstParamOfType<(x: string, y: number, z: boolean) => Date, number>` should be equivalent to `(x: string, z: boolean) => Date`.

---

First we should probably write something that operates on [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), since TypeScript can freely transform back and forth from tuple types to function argument lists (using, for example, [the `Parameters<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype)), and it's easier to manipulate tuples via [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) than it is to do the equivalent with functions.  So once we have a `RemoveFirstElementOfType<T, V>` where `T` is a tuple type, we can use it to write `RemoveFirstParamOfType<T>` like this:

```
type RemoveFirstParamOfType<T extends (...args: any) => any, V> = (
    ...args: RemoveFirstElementOfType<Parameters<T>, V>
) => ReturnType<T>
```

We're also using [the `ReturnType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) there.

---

So how do we write `RemoveFirstElementOfType<T, V>`?  Well, here's one approach:

```
type RemoveFirstElementOfType<T extends any[], V, A extends any[] = []> =
    T extends [infer F, ...infer R] ? (
        [F] extends [V] ? [...A, ...R] : (
            T extends [...infer FF, ...R] ?
            RemoveFirstElementOfType<R, V, [...A, ...FF]> :
            never
        )
    ) : A
```

This is a [tail-recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types), where `RemoveFirstElementOfType` is defined in terms of itself.  For it to be tail-recursive we need to use an *accumulator* type `A` to store intermediate results; this [defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to the empty tuple.

The basic approach there is to walk through `T` until we find an element assignable to `V`, at which point we drop it.  This is done by splitting `T` into its first element `F` and the rest of the tuple `R`.  If `T` is assignable to `V`, then we're done, and we can return the intermediate result `A` and the rest of the tuple `R` concatenated together (and throw away `F`).  Otherwise, we recurse using `R` instead of `T`, and `A`-with-`F`-on-the-end instead of `A`.  If we run off the end of `T` then we've failed to find a `V` so we might as well just return the whole tuple unchanged (which is by using the accumulated `A`).

The only difference between the above description and the actual code is that I do an extra step where I repackage `F` into a new tuple `FF` and use that instead.  And I only do that in order to preserve [tuple labels](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements), working around a missing feature described at [microsoft/TypeScript#49122](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49122).  By preserving the labels, we'll preserve the function parameter names.  It doesn't matter to the type system, `(x: string, z: boolean) => Date` and `(_arg0: string, _arg1: boolean) => Date` are the same type, but if the original function was `(x: string, y: number, z: boolean) => Date`, we'd probably prefer the first one for documentation purposes.

---

Okay, let's try it out:

```
type X = RemoveFirstParamOfType<
    (x: string, y: number, z: boolean) => Date, number>;
// type X = (x: string, z: boolean) => Date
```

Looks good. Let's do it with `Action`:

```
type UpdateAction = RemoveFirstParamOfType<Action, Value>
/* type UpdateAction = (
    product: Product, 
    cart: Cart, 
    payload?: { [key: string]: any; } | undefined
) => void */
```

Also looks good.  Now you can define `updateAction` as an `UpdateAction` and use it accordingly:

```
const updateProduct: UpdateAction = (product, cart) => {
    cart.name = product.name;
};

const Reducer = (
    product: Product,
    message: Message,
    cart: Cart,
    value: Value
) => {
    const { action, payload } = message;

    switch (action) {
        case 'update':
            updateProduct(product, cart);
            break;
        default: {
            throw new Error('Unknown type');
        }
    }
};
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-sgABpB-sCy1gWUI+3Snq9bEZAzM64gRh+ABG0GZAC86G-KJQhFMTUGQAEQ4KZkBfd9oDpMQAHo4OQX4D2PNk7wfLJv1-f9AJAYDkDAyA7GQlAAFU2HA9oKGoE9gQHQUYThPwx2lKjOlVEYIHVOCACokNNcj2EgNiaLQnpmDmFZFkkpJmR6TYPB2LY5OUI5ZHkc4vEuLQMKMSlzCeHhkEYfEIBgUAIFYDVaQZD4qmQHi4L3BBqF0YyKMgJZ5m2ZBBMojpRL6CTllk5AFLAfCUjCrYiTSFA2WC7zYvlGwxEIFyQDcoF5jjMTVJknyvJWfYSACLBcECNBMGwPASuixTkF2VYemGCYxk46ytSijK3PwMgApAZk1JOQy2TKmqIDS5QMAAd2AMAEAACz6chOmpKLlE2DAUCYDyIHoRda1IFghIgIqkl6RLivqiKLCO5A3ygCA4HUO71n4eBGAEHyNoOMBFriGbIIgIHhSgOIoF6ehSJAdQQEoGauhI+gXjelRnlIWxrCAA)